# Coordinates of clustplot function in R

Tags: clustering, k-means

Here is my data set. After applying clustering on two variables Annual income and Spending score, I tried visualizing it using clustplot. I haven't scaled any of these variables before applying kmeans.

I'm unable to interpret the coordinates which look like some principle components. What exactly they refer to? why minus values are being shown in the graph even though there are no values as such.

```
CustomerID,Genre,Age,Annual Income (k$),Spending Score (1-100)
0001,Male,19,15,39
0002,Male,21,15,81
0003,Female,20,16,6
0004,Female,23,16,77
0005,Female,31,17,40
0006,Female,22,17,76
0007,Female,35,18,6


library(cluster)
clusplot(x, kmeans$cluster, lines = 0, shade =  TRUE, color = TRUE, labels = 2, plotchar = FALSE, span = TRUE, main = paste("Clusters of client"), xlab = "Annual income", ylab = "spending score")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `?clusplot`, you are referred to `?clusplot.default`, where, under "Details", you find:

> ‘clusplot’ uses function calls ‘princomp(, cor = (ncol(x) > 2))’
>        or ‘cmdscale(, add=TRUE)’, respectively, depending on ‘diss’
>        being false or true.  These functions are data reduction
>        techniques to represent the data in a bivariate plot.

`diss` is by default `FALSE`, so your coordinates indeed come from a PCA.

Comment: can you help me what parameter should I change in order to make the plot on actual coordinates instead of components?

Comment: From the help pages, it doesn't look like there is an option for that. You may need to write your own function.